# Confluence plugin : How to put CSS markup in soy plugin?

Tags: css, confluence, soy-templates

I have a soy file that works fine, apart from the CSS style I'd like applied is ignored.

I suspect the CSS file is not imported into the page when loaded.

This is the line I have, the css-style is called 'urlwidth'

```
       <input id="vname" class="text urlwidth" type="text" name="vName">
```

The css file looks like this... (simplebp.css)

```
.urlwidth
{
    max-width: 350px;
}
```

I presume I'm meant to add a resources line to the soy file like this...

```
{webResourceManager_requireResource('com.example.plugins.tutorial.confluence.simplebp.simplebp:create-by-sample-template:simplebp-resources')}
```

I'm just not sure what the syntax is that I'm meant to put in the webResourceManager_requireResource.

Answer (score 0):

`webResourceManager_requireResource` function takes one parameter which is a (web resource) module key. As per [web resource module documentation](https://developer.atlassian.com/confdev/confluence-plugin-guide/confluence-plugin-module-types/web-resource-module):
"Web Resource plugin modules allow plugins to define downloadable resources"

You can define a web resource in your [plugin descriptor](https://developer.atlassian.com/docs/getting-started/configuring-the-plugin-descriptor) (/src/main/resources/atlassian-plugin.xml):

```
<atlassian-plugin name="My plugin" key="com.mydomain.example.plugin" plugins-version="2">
    (...)
    <web-resource key="my-css-resource">
        <resource type="download" name="my-css.css" location="/css/my-css.css"/>
    </web-resource>
</atlassian-plugin>
```

Assuming your plugin's code is laid out using the [Standard Directory Layout](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html) the `my-css.css` file should be in `<project>/src/main/resources/css/` directory.

The resource then can be referenced in the soy template by identifier of form `<plugin-key>:<resource-key>`:

```
{webResourceManager_requireResource('com.mydomain.example.plugin:my-css-resource')}
```

Reference:
[webResourceManager_requireResource function implementation](https://bitbucket.org/atlassian/atlassian-soy-templates/src/master/plugin/src/main/java/com/atlassian/soy/impl/functions/RequireResourceFunction.java?at=issue%2FSOY-48&fileviewer=file-view-default)

Comment: I've tried the above and I can't get it to work. As soon as I add this like to the soy file(   {webResourceManager_requireResource('com.example.plugins.tutorial.confluence:simplebp-resources')}  )  then the page stops loading. I can't find a log to tell me why its not loading. I'm just stuck. grrrr.

Comment: What does your plugin descriptor (atlassian-plugin.xml) look like?